# Set Gmap Icon to different categories with php

Tags: php, icons, categories

I am a rookie with PHP, so here's my question.

I want to add a custom marker ICON on GoogleMap to each category.

Here what I want to do: icon:

```
"if php listing-type=6 ?>/images/red-marker.png"<br/>
"if php listing-type=7 ?>/images/blue-marker.png"
```

The code I have:

```
options: {
    icon : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/red-marker.png"
},
```

Here it´s the full code:

http://descubrime.com.ar/fullcode.txt

And here its the site:

http://descubrime.com.ar/

I am completly lost!

Comment: are you getting any errors. A blank page? anything suspicious? I tried to debug your code in chrome but I dont have the full code

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you are asking, but I am almost sure you want something like this. **Please alert me if you were asking something else.**

Since you are a beginner, I will try and explain myself.

```
<?php
$parentDirectory = get_template_directory_uri();
$listingType = getListingType();
$icon = ""

if($listingType == 6)
{
    $icon = $parentDirectory . "/images/red-marker.png"
}
else
{
    $icon = $parentDirectory . "/images/blue-marker.png"
}
?>




options: {
        icon : "<?php echo $icon; ?>"
    },
```

Your basic question is to inject the path of your icon dynamically in your javascript. So anywhere before the `options` line, you start to declare the above php code and declare your `parentDirectory` and the `listing type`. I have used a method `getListingType()` which can be anything to get the listing (6, 7 whatever). Then based on the type I prepare my `$icon` variable which contains the dynamic path to your actual file.